# How to track browser contextmenu delete event in core javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way we can catch the delete event when we do a right click on selected text(in textarea or textbox element) and choose the 'Delete' option for Firefox, IE and Opera browsers?

[Right click from the browser's context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XyGf.png)

Comment: I would guess the input event would be triggered. Not sure you can prevent it if that is what you are after.

Comment: Hey @epascarello, this worked like a charm. Indeed the 'input' event is getting triggered in this case and I am able to catch it and process accordingly. Thank you soooo much. :)